# what is the unicode for file attachment symbol

Tags: unicode

How to get the **unicode** of **file attachment** symbol for my ios app.

I am making an chat app where i need to provide file attachment symbol
to upload files. 
can anyone give the unicode for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the answer. Hope it will be helpul for someone else -
***Unicode U+1F4CE***
You can refer this link  https://www.emojibase.com/emoji/1f4ce/paperclip

Copy it to the clipboard: